# Jmeter - saving the result using file name

Tags: jmeter

I need to append the summary result into CSV file, I tried but getting below error

[image: 1]

```
2022-08-04 12:21:25,553 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Unknown column name 
2022-08-04 12:21:25,553 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: C:\Users\Premkumar\Desktop\onescv.csv does not appear to have a valid header. Using default configuration.
2022-08-04 12:21:25,553 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Cannot parse timestamp: '', will try following formats [yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss]
2022-08-04 12:21:25,553 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService:  did not match yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, trying next date format
2022-08-04 12:21:25,553 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService:  did not match yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss, trying next date format
2022-08-04 12:21:25,553 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService:  did not match yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, trying next date format
2022-08-04 12:21:25,553 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService:  did not match yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, trying next date format
2022-08-04 12:21:25,553 INFO o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService:  did not match MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss, trying next date format
2022-08-04 12:21:25,553 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Error parsing field 'timeStamp' at line 1. java.text.ParseException: No date-time format found matching
```

I have tried by changing the date formats in Jmeter properties also as below;

```
# Timestamp format - this only affects CSV output files
# legitimate values: none, ms, or a format suitable for SimpleDateFormat
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

If any suggestion pls`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter's [.jtl files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) have the defined format like:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1659509834675,57,Your-Sampler-Label,200,OK,Thread Group 1-6,text,true,,114,0,12,12,null,25,0,3
```

When you use `Save Table Data` button in the [Summary Report listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) the first 2 lines look like:

```
Label,# Samples,Average,Min,Max,Std. Dev.,Error %,Throughput,Received KB/sec,Sent KB/sec,Avg. Bytes
Your-Sampler-Label,42,282,53,490,132.23,0.000%,32.25806,3.59,0.00,114.0
```

JMeter is looking for a [Unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) like `1659509834675` and it gets `Your-Sampler-Label` instead which is causing the failure.

So there is no way to add the Summary Report data to the .jtl results file without breaking Listeners and [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) generation, if you want to have Summary Report listener output as CSV you can use [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterpluginscmd) as:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv summary-report.csv --input-jtl /path/to/your/test/result.jtl --plugin-type SynthesisReport
```

This way you will have the Summary Report listener as a separate file.